# How To WPF DynamicResource + variable value for Label Content

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, resources, label

Hy Community,

I have a rather simple poblem but I can't find the solution.

I tried to simplifiy my code:

```
void myFunction()
    {
        StackPanel myStack = new StackPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Label myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.SetResourceReference(Label.ContentProperty, "LableName");
            this.Resources["LableName"] = "Lable";
            myStack.Children.Add(myLabel);
        }
    }
```

Now the result should be:

Label 0

Label 1

...

Label 9

How to do this by using Dynamic Resources?

Thank you!

Comment: Think it over, right now does not make sense, 10 times you set the same.

Comment: I know that this example make no sense.
But i dont know where to place my "i". That's why I'm asking.

Comment: myLabel.Content = "LableName " + i; SetResourceReference = DynamiResource but in this case I do not see clear need so that use it.

Comment: I want to program a multilanguage program. And due to this I solve it by DynamicResources... Do you understand?

Comment: I am still confused. First think what you want to gain and then get back.

Comment: I have List of same items. The user can switch the language of the item names. This i solved with dynamic resources...now i want display 10 items in the right language plus the number..